# react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED - Build Failed(React-native version - 0.67.2)

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

Adnroid Build failed with below errors:

```
 Task :react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
    
 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

React-native version - 0.67.2

react-native-code-push - 7.0.4

Answer (score 2):

This error can be resolved by updating JDK version to 11, or for my case 18.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/2184

Just a note for M1 mac, I follow this tutorial to get set up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq3ppMu2iuk